# Scraping *.aspx content using Python

Tags: asp.net, python, web-scraping

I'm having difficulties scraping dynamically generated table in ASPX. Trying to scrape the gas prices from a site like this [GasPrices](http://www.coloradogasprices.com/). I can extract all the information in the gas price table (address, time submitted etc.), except for the actual gas price.

Is there a way I could scrape the gas prices? i.e. somehow get a text representation of it. I'm not very familiar with ASP/ASPX - but what's being generated now is not showing up in the final HTML. I'm using Python to do the scraping, but that's irrelevant unless there's a specific library...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What gas prices? What is that link to?

Comment: oops. wrong link. fixed.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741420/scraping-aspx-content-using-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>The origin of the page (aspx) is not an issue here.</strike>

It looks like they're actively trying to thwart scraping attempts. The numbers are not fonts, rather they several div elements next to one another with [background images](http://www.coloradogasprices.com/images/art/p_g.png) that are numbers. *They really don't want to be scraped.*

(of course, if you were really determined you could probably map the class name of the div to... They're not very well 'encrypted')

**Take note of the copyright notice at the bottom of the linked page**

Comment: Agreed, the fact that they're encoding their prices with images suggests that they don't want to be scraped.  You should respect that.

Comment: Absolutely will respect that. Thanks.